# unable to prompt for read passwd from shell script

Tags: shell-script, github

In the below script it is not waiting for `passwd` to enter it is ending with error message.

```
$ sudo ssh -i crowdpersona_key root@xx.xx.xx.xx bash -c ' git clone user@github.com/test1/crowdpersona.git && cd crowdpersona && mkdir attachments'
Error message : fatal: could not read Password for 'https://user@github.com': No such device or address
```

Comment: Why the `sudo`?

Comment: `ssh -i` awaits an identity-file, but you're providing username/hostname afterwards.

Comment: edited my question, -i is for adding the .key file as input

Answer (score 2):

You do not need or want the -i on the ssh command.

The -i selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.

see

```
man ssh
```

Your command will work:

```
sudo ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx bash -c ' git clone https://user@github.com/test1/crowdpersona.git && cd crowdpersona && mkdir attachments'
```

Comment: i am using -i select the file( key) ,    earlier i missed it while posting                                                                                                          **sudo ssh -i crowdpersona_key root@xx.xx.xx.xx bash -c ' git clone https://user@github.com/test1/crowdpersona.git && cd crowdpersona && mkdir attachments'**

Comment: @AshaDatla if that is the case please correct your question using the [edit] button

Answer (score -2):

`user@github.com/test1/crowdpersona.git` is probably not a valid GitHub project URL. It's either `git@github.com:user/project.git` for Git over SSH, or `https://github.com/user/project.git` for Git over HTTPS. When presented with a non-existent project URI, GitHub asks for authentication (probably for looking up private repos):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git
Cloning into 'bar'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

The `git` command is not able to read a password or username here presumably because no TTY is allocated.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git
Cloning into 'bar'...
Username for 'https://github.com': ^C
$ ssh localhost git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git
Cloning into 'bar'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

The solution is usually to use the correct project URI.